# PendingIntent while screen locked don´t launch desired Activity

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I followed the [doc for notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) and the [gcm example](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MyGcmListenerService.java)
Everything works fine when the device is awake, the notification sound, vibration and the desired Activity works as expected, but none of these works the right way when device is locked.

Even if the app is open or in background, the notification open the main activity instead of the desired one.
Here is my code:

```
JSONObject request=messageContent.getJSONObject("request");
intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewRequest.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
intent.putExtra(NewRequest.REQUEST, String.valueOf(request));

Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, id, intent,
       PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentText(body)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))
        .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000 })
        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "My Tag");
wl.acquire(10000);

notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

Also tried to keep the navigation flow with this for the pending intent, but the result is the same.

```
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(NewRequest.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

PendingIntent pendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(id, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

I have no idea why this works only when the screen is not locked